# Know when drive mounts but without a drive letter

Tags: hard-drive, windows-explorer, drive-letter

I have some external drives for which I've not assigned a drive letter but, instead, have let Windows 10 create a shortcut for that drive. If I plug in the drive and wait a few moments, I can then double-click on that shortcut and get into the drive's root directory.

Here's the problem: That drive doesn't show up on "this PC" and, as a former Mac user, that's what I expect. Suffice to say, I'd like to see *something* that indicates the drive is, indeed, mounted.

Is there something I'm missing or do I simply have to let Windows assign a drive letter (which may change because I have many drives and use them in a manner that makes this happen)? There are some apps that complain about missing data files because Drive "F" is now Drive "Q". I do have a backup app called SyncBackSE that permits me to configure source and destination files using volume name or unique Serial ID (and that's great); but not all apps are written to permit this.

So, is there a solution I'm not seeing or do we continue to live in 1981's Drive Letter Hell?

Thanks,
Barry

Comment: Windows is not MAC and vice versa. I always assign drive letters to the devices I mount in my Windows computers.

Comment: If you manually assign a letter to a drive, it will be re-used for that drive (unless it's already taken).

Comment: Probably will end up assigning drive letters just so they pop up in "this PC". I'll then hide the drive letters and make sure I assign unique names to the volumes. Finally, I'll use the name or serial ID for the apps that support that (ie, SyncBackSE) and find replacement apps for those that do not. Thanks for the comments.